# $graphLookup in mongodb not returning result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Basically I have this type of data that I want to get relationship using $graphLookup

```
{_id: "111", pin: "8018", introducer: ""}
{_id: "222", pin: "042f", introducer: "8018"}
{_id: "333", pin: "1234", introducer: "042f"}
```

My output should be

```
{_id: "111", pin: "8018", introducer: "", treeView: []}
{_id: "222", pin: "042f", introducer: "8018", treeView: [{_id: "111", pin: "8018", introducer: ""}]}
{_id: "333", pin: "1234", introducer: "042f", treeView: [{_id: "111", pin: "8018", introducer: ""},{_id: "222", pin: "042f", introducer: "8018"} ]}
```

My code

```
userSchema.statics.getChildren = function(user){
return this.aggregate([
    { $graphLookup: {            
        from: "userSchema",
        startWith: "$introducer",
        connectFromField: "introducer",
        connectToField: "pin",
        as: "treeView"       
        }
    }
]);
```

};

However I am only getting blank array for treeView. Please help.

Comment: Try name of collection for "from" attribute

Comment: I have tried User, user, userSchema all giving blank array

Comment: users ? Have you tried ? check the name of collection. It will be plural if you have created collection through mongoose

Comment: Yes!! You're right. It is plural. Thank you so much. Wasted 4 hours for this.